# Not able to install/run pandas on jupyter getting error 'pandas' has no attribute

Tags: python, pandas

I've updated python via terminal, then re-install anaconda3 and still same error as below.

I also checked folders to find any name similarities and didn't find any "pandas" in my files.

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-bfa3005add70> in <module>
----> 1 pd.version
 
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
    261             return _SparseArray
    262 
--> 263         raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
    264 
    265 
 
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'version'
```

Comment: were you trying to print pandas version? use `pd.__version__`

Comment: Hi I've used your code and result is "'1.0.5'"

Comment: when I'm try to create series in pandas it's come back with:

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-824984974ce9> in <module>
----> 1 pd.series(my_list)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
    261             return _SparseArray
    262 
--> 263         raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
    264 
    265 

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'series'